# Diferencia versionCode y versionName en Android

Tags: android

¿Cual es la diferencia o para que sirve?

```
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Answer (score 8):

El [**versionCode**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) es un número que es usado para determinar si una versión es más reciente que otra. Este numero no es mostrado a los usuarios pero sirve para definir el numero de versión dentro de la Play Store.

El [**versionName**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) su único propósito es mostrar numero de versión de la aplicación a los usuarios.

Cuando subes aplicaciones, en la consola de desarrollo Play Store puedes ver el numero de **versionCode** y entre paréntesis el **versionName**, el **versionCode** es muy importante ya que mediante este numero se pueden administrar las versiones de aplicaciones dentro de Play Store, el **versionName**, es únicamente una descripción. Se puede tener el mismo **versionName** pero nunca el mismo **versionCode** por aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente únicamente se podian definir estos indicadores dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.puisorulmeu.drag"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >
```

Actualmente pueden ser definidos dentro del archivo `build.gradle` de tu aplicación, y sobreescriben a los valores definidos en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
...
...
android {
...
...
        versionCode 3
        versionName '1.2'
    }
...
```

---

Usando Xamarin el valor del `versionCode` se puede cambiar en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` en el atributo `android:versionCode`, ejemplo :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0.0.1" package="com.qgrouptechnology.qcontractor" android:versionCode="19">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Xamarin Android, no con Android nativo, y no existe ningún fichero build.gradle, ¿se trata de un fichero que pueda encontrarse en los subdirectorios del proyecto y se llama así tal cual en un proyecto creado con Android nativo?

Comment: Hola @Windgate Usando Xamarin el valor del `versionCode` se puede cambiar en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` en el atributo `android:versionCode`.

Comment: Hola @Jorge, acceso al Manifest sí que tengo, he llegado a este hilo de forma un poco colateral, lo que necesito añadir en el gradle es: splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
} para permitir que el emulador en modo Debug (x86) pueda instalar una apk compilada en modo Release (armeabi-v7a) (se sale bastante del contenido de este hilo...)

Comment: Si, tal vez se sale un poco, que te parece si realizas una nueva pregunta, puedes hacer referencia a esta creo que sería bueno incluso para la comunidad.

Comment: La verdad es que la comunidad Xamarin es un desierto, voy a ver si consigo averiguar algo más y si no intentaré postear, estos días estoy comentando bastante en los hilos de StackOverflow (inglés) y es raro encontrar contenido que tenga menos de 4 años y no esté deprecado. Estoy deseando terminar un proyecto con Xamarin y no volver a usarlo nunca más, espero que con MAUI (https://vicenteguzman.mx/2020/05/21/adios-xamarin-forms-hola-maui/) mejore la historia. Gracias anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**[Referencia](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)**

Traducción libre por mi:

### android:versionCode

> El número de versión interna. Este número es utilizado únicamente para determinar si una versión es más reciente que otra, con números más altos indicando las versiones más recientes. Este no es el número de versión mostrado a los usuarios; ese número es establecido por el atributo versonName.
> El valor debe ser un entero, tal como "100". Puedes definirlo como quieras, siempre que cada versión sucesiva tenga un número mayor. [...]

### android:versionName

> El nombre de la versión mostrado a los usuarios. Este atributo puede ser establecido directamente a una cadena de caracteres, o como referencia a un recurso de cadena de caracteres. La cadena de caracteres no tiene otro propósito que ser mostrado a los usuarios. El atributo versionCode almacena el número de versión significativo utilizado internamente.

De esto se puede interpretar que `versionName` es algo que solamente se muestra a los usuarios, pero no sirve para comparar o determinar que versión es más reciente. Para eso, el atributo que importa es versionCode. Para cada nueva versión de tu producto debes incrementar este último y todo funcionará como esperas.

Con información de [versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269683/255257)

Answer (score 0):

**Version code:** identificador interno de código. no permite decimales es decir numeración entera.

Cosas a tener en cuenta, cuando publiques una apk a la tienda, y despues más adelante quieras actualizarla, el version code debe ser superior al que ya está publicado en la tienda.

**versionName:** es la versión que se mostrará en la ficha google play.
normalmente usando estructura `1.0.0`

Dentro de `google play developer` en el apartado `estadísticas` solo se muestra las instalaciones actuales haciendo referencia solo al `version code`.
Para poder saber que `versión name` se refiere, recomiendo poner el mismo valor en ambos, eliminando los `.` en el `version code`

por ejemplo la versión 1.5.3 = 153 cuando llegues a 2.0.3 = 203, en estadísticas si ves algo versión `167` sabrás que se refiere a `1.6.7`